# ExecuteReader TimeOut solved by changing the name of the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, timeout

This happened to me today.
My MVC.Net application was running fine since few months. Today it caught error when executing this part of code.(this is the simplified version)

```
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = $"mySchema.myStoredProcedureName {param1};
db.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
db.Database.Connection.Open();  
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Where db is a DbContext EF6.
The timeOut occured on the last line
I tried the syntax "using" no success
I tried also the following, maybe the connection is not opened

```
while(db.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
db.Database.Connection.Open(); }
```

No! success.

**The stored procedure returns result in 2 seconds on SSMS.**

Finally I created a similar stored procedure with another name
Then it worked.

My question: 
- Did MSSQL blackList my stored procedure?

Comment: was the original name starting with sp_ ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: did you recreate the stored procedure?  This action can result in the stored procedure's query execution plans being refreshed, that might be what solved the problem.  Another way is to execute stored procedure using WITH RECOMPILE - see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @AndrewDeighton, I'll try that whenever it happens again, because I dropped the faulty procedure, thanks

Comment: @GuidoG it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it was blacklisted.  Is it possible that your indexes were in need of a rebuild?  In other words the renaming really may not have fixed the problem, but some other sort of SQL Server maintenance behind the scenes did?

My educated guess is the server provider did something to affect you if you did not change any code.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Why?  ( I am relatively new to being active on this forum, so no sarcasm meant )  Based on the question, why could it not be the answer?

Comment: Because allthough this information is usefull it is not an answer to his question. It only states one possible idea about the cause of the problem.

Comment: I am stating that something was fixed on the server, and renaming the proc really did not fix anything.

Comment: Which can be true but also cannot be true. Knowing this might help the OP to find out what happend but is not an answer imho

Comment: @MisterPositive, actually, I'm not in full control of the server, because we rent it from a provider.

Comment: And about the need of rebuild, I don't know because other SP were working

Comment: My educated guess is your provider did something to affect you., I updated my answer to reflect the new info.